# Can I import/store data files in a temp work library in Python?

Tags: python, import

I would like to work with .xlsx files, and I tried built-in `open()` and pandas `pd.read_excel()` functions, both of which work but I have to include them in the build each time and re-importing large data files takes a lot of time.

I'm more familiar with SAS where you can commit files to a WORK library, is there something similar with Python, maybe a package I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have 2 options to serialize your data and store it in a file

**pickle** files: one dataframe per file

```
df = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')
df.to_pickle('data.pkl')
```

**hdf5** files: multiple dataframes per file

```
df = pd.read_hdf('data.h5', 'myframe')
df.to_hdf('data.h5', 'myframe')
```

Both methods are way faster than using 'xlsx' files, use less disk space and preserve your objects structure and data types. I guess hdf5 is more what you had in mind with your 'library'.

see: [Pandas HDF5 (PyTables)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-hdf5)

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it. Was confused because I was trying to `read_pickle` before saving the data frame `to_pickle`, but this is exactly what I was looking for.